# aCharEngine BarGraph XTextLabel, Bar lining up

Tags: android, achartengine

Im using aChartEngine(1.2.0 jar) to generate a Bargraph chart with 7 bars.

Im having 2 problems.
The Bars are not aligned/centered to its "addXTextLabel".
When I increase the width of the bars, not all bars are displayed on the Chart.

The only bar that remains centered/aligned to its "XTextLabel" is Bar 4.

Here is my code

```
  public class BarGraph{

    private int background = 0xffffffff;

    private int bar1color = 0xff714596;
    private int bar2color = 0xff3386a5;
    private int bar3color = 0xff96e4e4;
    private int bar4color = 0xff75df51;
    private int bar5color = 0xfffff033;
    private int bar6color = 0xffffbf33;
    private int bar7color = 0xffff3333;

    private int titleColor = 0xff8d8d8d;



    public Intent getIntent(Context context) {
      int  s1 = 89;
      int  s2 = 74;
      int  s3 = 68;
      int  s4 = 59;
      int  s5 = 52;
      int  s6 = 40;
      int  s7 = 22;
      XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("Bar 1");
      XYSeries series2 = new XYSeries("Bar 2");
      XYSeries series3 = new XYSeries("Bar 3");
      XYSeries series4 = new XYSeries("Bar 4");
      XYSeries series5 = new XYSeries("Bar 5");
      XYSeries series6 = new XYSeries("Bar 6");
      XYSeries series7 = new XYSeries("Bar 7");

      series1.add(1, s1);
      series2.add(2, s2);
      series3.add(3, s3);
      series4.add(4, s4);
      series5.add(5, s5);
      series6.add(6, s6);
      series7.add(7, s7);


     XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
      dataset.addSeries(series1);
      dataset.addSeries(series2);
      dataset.addSeries(series3);
      dataset.addSeries(series4);
      dataset.addSeries(series5);
      dataset.addSeries(series6);
      dataset.addSeries(series7);



    // Customize bar 1
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setColor(bar1color);
    renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer.setChartValuesTextSize(18);
    //renderer.setLineWidth((float) 50.0d);


    // Customize bar 2
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer2.setColor(bar2color);
    renderer2.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer2.setChartValuesTextSize(18);
    //renderer2.setLineWidth((float) 50.0d);

    // Customize bar 3
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer3 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer3.setColor(bar3color);
    renderer3.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer3.setChartValuesTextSize(18);
    //renderer3.setLineWidth((float) 50.0d);

    // Customize bar 4
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer4 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer4.setColor(bar4color);
    renderer4.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer4.setChartValuesTextSize(18);
    //renderer4.setLineWidth((float) 50.0d);


    // Customize bar 5
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer5 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer5.setColor(bar5color);
    renderer5.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer5.setChartValuesTextSize(18);
    //renderer5.setLineWidth((float) 50.0d);

    // Customize bar 6
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer6 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer6.setColor(bar6color);
    renderer6.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer6.setChartValuesTextSize(18);
    //renderer6.setLineWidth((float) 50.0d);

    // Customize bar 7
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer7 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer7.setColor(bar7color);
    renderer7.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer7.setChartValuesTextSize(18);
    //renderer7.setLineWidth((float) 50.0d);


    // This is how the "Graph" itself will look like
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
     mRenderer.setChartTitle("Performance");
     mRenderer.setYTitle("Rating");
     mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(25);
     mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(25);
     mRenderer.setAxesColor(titleColor);
     mRenderer.setLabelsColor(titleColor);
     mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
     mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(background);
     mRenderer.setMarginsColor(background);
     mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false,false);
     mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false,false);
     mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 90, 15, 20 });
     mRenderer.setShowGridY(true);      
     mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
     mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
     mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
     mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
     mRenderer.setXAxisMax(8);
     mRenderer.setYAxisMax(100);
     mRenderer.addXTextLabel(1, "Bar 1");
     mRenderer.addXTextLabel(2, "Bar 2");
     mRenderer.addXTextLabel(3, "Bar 3");
     mRenderer.addXTextLabel(4, "Bar 4");
     mRenderer.addXTextLabel(5, "Bar 5");
     mRenderer.addXTextLabel(6, "Bar 6");
     mRenderer.addXTextLabel(7, "Bar 7");

     mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
     mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);
     mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer3);
     mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer4);
     mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer5);
     mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer6);
     mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer7);
     //mRenderer.setBarWidth(80);
     mRenderer.setBarSpacing(0);


    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(context, dataset,mRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);
    return intent;
  }

 }
```

[image: BarChart with no setBarWidth]

[image: BarChart with setBarWidth to 80]

So, what Im trying to achieve is to have all bar displayed on the chart, with a BarWidth of 80, and have the XTextLabel aligned to each corresponding bar.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had tried this before, but I seems I was making so many changes and trying different approaches I didn't realize this had worked. So with the code I posted above, I simply change

```
mRenderer.setBarWidth(100);
mRenderer.setBarSpacing(-50);
```

`Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(context, dataset,mRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);`

to

`Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(context, dataset,mRenderer, Type.STACKED);`

And I got the result I wanted

[image]